# Copy ad user sid to this user email account

Tags: sid

We are migrating users from other domain.
Now the users have user account, and email account.
We want just use email account to login, so just one account.
The question is how i can copy the user profile sid to email account sidhistory.
We need this cause of ntfs user right.
Or maybe there is any other solution, to copy the nfts right?